# view not showing store when initcomponent loads store extjs 4.1.1

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, view, treeview, extjs4

Using ExtJs 4.1.1

I have some stores that will need to be created for each instance of a particular view. So, I am creating these stores within the initcomponent method of the view. This is all part of a refactoring of some code I am doing. I am attempting to make this view component able to be instantiated with multiple instances, while have a single controller take care of all instances. My goals aside, here is what I am doing:

A particular treestore is populated with data(doesn't matter how, the data does end up in the store as verified with firebug). A treeview is defined within the view, and it takes the populated treestore as its store. However, when the view comes up. The data is not in the treeview. I beleive this may have something to do with all the static config loading before initComponent runs, although I am not sure. If I could get some insight on that process, it would be very helpful. I am thinking I say this.store1 belongs to the view in the view config, but then define this.store1 within the views initComponent. Is this the wrong way to do it???

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Using ExtJs 4.1.1

Comment: If it is the case of execution order. Where can I define data elements(stores) for the view and view items prior to loading the config?

Comment: I thought to maybe try constructor instead of initcomponent but I have the same results.

Comment: a little code would help

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the name of the store from the store list of your controller, because this mechanism interferes whith assigning IDs to stores somehow. Here is an example from my experience:

```
Ext.define('Adminpanel.controller.MenuManager', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['Menu'] // <-- reason
});

Ext.define('Adminpanel.view.menuManager.Tree', {
   extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
   initComponent: function() {
       this.store = Ext.create('Adminpanel.store.Menu'); // <-- problem
       this.callParent(arguments);
   }
});
```